# why remoteMessage from FCM dont work in background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i send message from server, only work when app is running in foreground.
I send message with payload and notification body.
if app is running in background onMessageReceived is not called.
what could be failing
My code n Manifest

```
 <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo_mediano" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
       <service
            android:name=".mackey.FCMService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"

            android:resource="@drawable/ic_menu_camera">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        </aplication>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My service class:

```
        public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

    public FCMService() {
    }
   @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
     sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        System.out.println("remote message");
     
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            Log.d(LOGTAG, "NOTIFICATION");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
             Log.d(LOGTAG, "DATA");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Title php : " + remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Image: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("image"));
           
        }
    }
```

graddle Module App

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
```

Logcat in Background:

```
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
I/FirebaseMessaging: Starting download of: https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/imagen-tridimensional-coche-taxi-aislado-fondo-blanco_53876-12108.jpg
W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Logcat in foreground:

```
I/System.out: remote message
D/android-fcm: NOTIFICATION
D/android-fcm: new Notification
D/android-fcm: DATA
D/android-fcm: Title php : data  php
D/android-fcm: Title php : default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When app is in background, onMessageReceived is not called until users taps on notification associated with push message.
If you want the system to call onMessageReceived without user tapping on notification, try to send a silent push message.